# Behavior of OpenGL textured quads with alpha values (font glyph clipping or masking)

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha

I don't think I've got any syntax errors, just a problem with understanding how alpha
is done on textured quads with OpenGL.   (mesa 9.0 under centos 6.3, which is opengl 4.2 I think)

I've got a font face that has been uploaded with glTexImage (I've tried GL_ALPHA, GL_RED and currently GL_RGBA).   I'm fairly certain the alpha channel is set on the letter and unset on the background, since I twiddled the pixels and set it manually).

So, just to clarify, the TexImage contains red 0xff0000 on the letter pixels, black 0x000000 on background pixels, and the alpha is set to 0xff on the red pixels, and 0x00 otherwise.

I did:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE );
```

before

```
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 
    face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 
    0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, new_buffer );
```

When showing the glyph with:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ascii_textures[100] );

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
// Then draw the box
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );           
    glVertex2f( ...                          // bottom left
    glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );
    glVertex2f( ...                          // top left
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );
    glVertex2f( ...                          // top right
    glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );
    glVertex2f( ...                         // bottom right
glEnd();
```

I get this (I'm drawing the red 'd' over the videos):

[image: Without glColor]

If I uncomment the glColor line, I get:

[image: With glColor]

If I don't use the texture, I get a translucent dark box, so obviously blending is working.

It appears that OpenGL is pulling the alpha value from the glColor4f statement, but not from the texture.

Anyway to make it look at the texture and not the color?

What I'm really doing is trying to mask or clip the glyphs that I preloaded as textures, so other ways to go about this would be welcomed (though probably not glut fonts since I'll need complicated unicode glyphs at some point)

Comment: With `glColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`, you shouldn't be getting a red letter -- it should be black. Have you got any shader enabled? Any other modes we should be aware of? `glMaterial` stuff for instance?

Comment: As a minimal test case, you could create a 4-byte array in code and upload it as an 1x1 texture. Use `{0, 0, 1, 1}` to be certain that you get the order right; you should get a blue block.

Comment: @Thomas: If the texture environment mode is set to GL_REPLACE or GL_DECAL, then a black base color will have no effect on the texture. In fact I think OP has enabled GL_REPLACE mode.

Comment: no glMaterial stuff;   Just learning about shaders now.   My last time using opengl before this year was on SGI machines :0      The texture is red (for me to figure out which is which).   I tried GL_DECAL earlier, no difference (white background).

Comment: no reference to GL_REPLACE anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'll close this, since I did a workaround by drawing outside of
OpenGL and then uploading the entire texture.   Not quite what I 
wanted, but will work for now.